# Transfer Function of Non-Ideal Transformer

Tags: transformer, programming, simulation, control-system, practical

What is the mathematical relationship between primary and secondary windings?

It can be either in the s-domain, or a time domain expression.

This expression must contain all realistic parameters, like core losses, hysteresis losses, winding inductances, mutual inductance between windings, effect of frequency, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @LeonHeller I want to simulate a transformer.

Comment: Use a SPICE simulation.

Comment: @hkBattousai - Programming simulators is off-topic here.  It sounds like you're more interested in the transfer function anyways, so I'll strip that part from your question.  If you need to know how to program a simulator given operational parameters/a transfer function (and still don't want to use SPICE), then search for a duplicate and go to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen any formula as the non-linear behavior as a function of freq. depends on stray and winding capacitance, ferrite non-linear properties and many other factors.

For 60Hz here's a simple model http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~johnsodw/egr325mine/paper2/paper2.html

Which are very different to RF tansformers
http://www.minicircuits.com/app/AN20-002.pdf

which are very different to pulse SMPS transformers !

which are very different to Flyback transformers !
http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-flyback-transformer.htm